# C: From char array to linked list

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list, char

I'm still learning how to program in C and I've stumbled across a problem. 
Using a char array, I need to create a linked list, but I don't know how to do it. I've searched online, but it seems very confusing. The char array is something like this `char arr[3][2]={"1A","2B","3C"};`

Comment: are you familiar with linked list? do you know how to implement it yourself? (regardless of the array)

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/) tutorial, and swap `int` for `char[2]` in the `node` struct.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code below. It uses a `Node` struct and you can see how we iterate through the list, creating nodes, allocating memory, and adding them to the linked list. It is based of [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/) GeeksForGeeks article, with a few modifications. I reccommend you compare the two to help understand what is going on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
        char value[2];
        struct Node * next;
};

int main() {

        char arr[3][2] = {"1A","2B","3C"};

        struct Node * linked_list = NULL;

        // Iterate over array
        // We calculate the size of the array by using sizeof the whole array and dividing it by the sizeof the first element of the array
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++) {
                // We create a new node
                struct Node * new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
                // Assign the value, you can't assign arrays so we do each char individually or use strcpy
                new_node->value[0] = arr[i][0];
                new_node->value[1] = arr[i][1];
                // Set next node to NULL
                new_node->next = NULL;

                if (linked_list == NULL) {
                        // If the linked_list is empty, this is the first node, add it to the front
                        linked_list = new_node;
                        continue;
                }

                // Find the last node (where next is NULL) and set the next value to the newly created node
                struct Node * last = linked_list;
                while (last->next != NULL) {
                        last = last->next;
                }
                last->next = new_node;
        }

        // Iterate through our linked list printing each value
        struct Node * pointer = linked_list;
        while (pointer != NULL) {
                printf("%s\n", pointer->value);
                pointer = pointer->next;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

There are a few things the above code is missing, like checking if each `malloc` is successful, and `free`ing the allocated memory afterwards. This is only meant to give you something to build off of!